# Is there anything wrong with praying on one's bed?

Tags: salat

Sometimes the ground can be too hard when praying on an ordinary prayer mat; and I end up with bruises on my knees.  However, there is a more comfortable alternative...

**Question**: Is there anything wrong with praying on one's bed?

I've asked people about this, and they've expressed skepticism, but I don't see any reason why it's wrong.  I'm guessing people think it's not the sunnah, rather than there being anything inherently wrong with it.

I've found it's also more convenient when traveling (not needing to carry a prayer mat) or in hospital.

Comment: Maybe you should avoid praying the hanafi style as they go down for sujud from standing position with the knees first ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is permissible to pray on one’s bed so long as it is clean, firm (will not shake or wobble and distract the worshipper) and the worshipper is able to place his forehead and nose firmly when prostrating.

> 1- Al-Hattaab said in Mawaahib al-Jaleel (1/520): It says in al-Tawdeeh: As for praying on one’s bed, there is no dispute that it is permissible, as is stated in al-Bayaan.
>
> 2 – al-Nawawi (may Allaah have mercy on him) said in al-Majmoo’ (3/221): The condition for obligatory prayer is that the worshipper be steady in facing the qiblah throughout the prayer. If he faces the qiblah and does all the pillars (essential parts) of prayer in a howdah or on a bed or the like on the back of a riding-animal that is standing, there are two views as to whether his obligatory prayer is valid; the more correct view is that it is valid, and this was stated by the majority, because that is like praying on board a ship.